# django form field error_messages not working with IntegerField

Tags: python, django, forms

This is my model :

```
class Bid(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    bid = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Prix demandé', null=False, blank=False)
    note = models.TextField(verbose_name='Description', null=False, blank=False)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is my form

```
class BidForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = ['bid', 'note']

    bid = forms.IntegerField(error_messages={'invalid': 'Please enter a valid bid'})
```

When the bid is invalid, I always get the default error message not the one I specificed

> Ensure this value is greater than or equal to 1

However it works if I add another field of another type, like `CharField`

```
class BidForm(forms.ModelForm):

    ....

    bid = forms.IntegerField(error_messages={'invalid': 'Please enter a valid bid'})
    text = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'Please enter a valid text'})
```

> Ensure this value is greater than or equal to 1.

> Please enter a valid text

This is my view

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, id=self.kwargs['id'])
    form = BidForm(request.POST)
    form.fields['bid'].validators = [MinValueValidator(1)]
    if form.is_valid():
        bid = form.save(commit=False)
        bid.user = request.current_user
        bid.project = project
        bid.save()
        return redirect(....)
    else:
        c = {'project':project, 'form': form}
        return render(....)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your view change the following line

```
form.fields['bid'].validators = [MinValueValidator(1,message='Please enter a valid bid')]
```

and remove

```
bid = forms.IntegerField(error_messages={'invalid': 'Please enter a valid bid'})
```

form your form